# How to solve problem of numerical and factor data in single column?

Tags: r, machine-learning

We know whenever we arrange dataset in R. We arrange independent and dependent variable column-wise for each ID.

But if I see numerical and category data in single column of independent variable, how can I use that for predicting?

Example, for 10 ID's.
Past number of calls: 1,3,4,2,0,no past,5,1,no past, 6(note:no past have different behaviour than 0)

And some other independent variables
And one target column.

So from the example, I don't want all levels as factor levels. I want to solve as by looking if 'no past' or as numeric(0-6).

How can I do so, I tried to make different column for 'no past'. But what would I place in 'past number of calls'.

Comment: I am voting to leave this open. Although it's asked with regard to R, these issues would exist no matter what software you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just code no past as 0 in the 'past number of calls; column, and add another factor column for 'no past', which takes one of two values. This gives you all the same information, but allows the columns to have either numeric or factor types.

Comment: As 0 has different behaviour than 'no past'. Would not this create bias?

Comment: Not when used in conjunction with the "no past" binary column. The "no past" column accounts for the different behavior.

Comment: So, can I write 0-6 any number for 'no past' in 'past number of calls'? as conjunction will account for.

Comment: Yep. For example, if you were to use this in a regression, increasing the numeric value for 'no past' would be reflected by a linear change in the coefficient for the binary 'no past' column.